# Вопрос по UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, ios

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы в поле textfield нельзя было ввести буквы?

Делаю простенький конвертер, и при вводе букв в перемежку с цифрами и буквами при дальнейшем нажатии на кнопку конвертировать ответ получается другой, чем когда без букв.

Как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: давайте ка, еще раз с запятыми... пожалуйста. что касается первого предложения ща отвечу.

Comment: при вводе цифр и букв в поле textfield вперемежку  и дальнейшем нажатии на кнопку конвертировать, у меня получается неправильный результат
как это исправить? какие строчки нужно добавить в код?
 x = [tempField.text doubleValue];
    
    
    
    y =  (x - 32)/1.8;
    
    NSString*result = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Celsius %g ",y];
        
    
    [tempResult setText: result];

Answer (score 1):

У класса `UITextField` есть свойство delegate. Туда запихиваем делегат, а в делегате реализуем один метод по теме:

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли!

Comment: т.е. второй вопрос отпал?

Comment: я просто подумал, что таким способом вообще запретить ввод букв, а как тогда решить 2-ой вопрос?

Comment: Тупо после нажатии нейкой кнопки обработать введеный текст, как нужно и все.