# 2 вопроса по поводу цветного стригра и UITextField

Tags: xcode, objective-c

1-й вопрос.
Строка должна выглядит так: 123+, или 123-.
В общем мне нужно в строку знак + или знак - разного цвета, цвет задам [UIColor redColor];
Но чтоб основной не менялся как сделать?
знаки лежат в разных переменных

```
smain=txtfield.text;//числа без знака (например 123)
s1=@%"+";
s2=@%"-";
```

2-й вопрос.
Как ограничить ввод символов в UITextField, например можно вводить только 5 символов, 6-й не введёться, и если 6-й вводишь, то алерт выскочит например что нельзя.(у меня есть вариантик, но это уж на крайний момент, когда нажимаешь кнопку, происходит подсчёт символов, и если привышает, то удаляет последнии символы 6-й,7-й,и тд. ну и алерт конечно, но не хочу я так есть системные какието настройки?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что касается 1 вопроса, то UILabel имеет для этого Атрибутные строки:

```
    NSString *smain=txtfield.text;
    NSString *s1=@"+";
    NSString *s2=@"-";

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:smain attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];
    NSAttributedString *attributedS1String = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s1 attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}];
    NSAttributedString *attributedS2String = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s2 attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
    [mutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:attributedS1String];
    [mutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:attributedS2String];

    UILabel *textlabel = [UILabel new];
    [textlabel setAttributedText:mutableAttributedString];
```

Что касается второго [вот наводка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317126#317130) дальше сами

Comment: спасибо, по поводу 2-го, нужно количество, а в теме разделение цыфр и букв

Comment: ну суть то не  в этом, а втом что метод делегата возвращает YES или NO. Проверьте строку на длину то и верните.

Comment: Сразу не совсем допёр, почему то у меня не получилось вывести цвет в тексте, всё как было чёрное, щас всё нормально)))

Comment: Можно пример в студию?

Comment: Да всё работает, как ты написал, спасибо